# How to prevent the activation of the loading screen when sending Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an loading system like bottom code.

```
         <div class="loadin-container" id="loding-container">
            <div class="loadin-image">
                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $vitrin_options_loading_image; ?>" alt="loading">
            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .loadin-container {
                background-color: #fff;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 999;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center
            }

            .loadin-image {
                margin: auto 0 auto 0;
                position: relative
            }

            .loading-display-none {
                animation: loading-outro 1.6s
            }

            .dsnone {
                display: none
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function loading() {
                document.getElementById("loding-container").classList.add("loading-display-none");

                function dsnone() {
                    document.getElementById("loding-container").classList.add("dsnone");
                }

                setTimeout(function() {
                    dsnone();
                }, 1500);
            };
            window.onload = (event) => {
                loading();
            };
        </script>
```

It's ok and working perfectly.
The problem is seen when the Ajax request is sent and DOM on all page to display new content and in this moment loading screen started displaying without displaying none after many second.

I try to delete loading div after 3 second to prevent displaying it but it steel is my problem and not solved.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById("loding-container").remove();
}, 3000);
```

I don't know how to solve it.
Is there any other loading system method to work perfect ?

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with the *"ajax request and DOM on *all page*"*.  How do you trigger the ajax?  You might be doing a full reload if you have a `form` and `<button>`.   Or, more likely, your "all page" ajax also includes the loading panel.

Comment: @freedomn-m Actually I'm developing my Wordpress theme and the problem is with Yith product ajax filter plugin. its triggers when product filter apply and I dont have access to modify this ajax requests